# Asp.NET Core Flow Charts generations

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, workflow, flowchart

[image]

I have data in my database which translate above flow in below form

```
**CurrentState       NextPossibleState**

OPEN            Resolve
OPEN            Closed
OPEN            INPROGRESS and so on..
```

.

I am currently working on Asp.net core mvc application. 
I am looking for free plugins/library which can generate above like flow chart to give a visual view.

Can anybody advise on that..

Comment: Looking for the same thing right now, feel free to update your question if you've found something :)

Answer (score 1):

flowchart.js is a jQuery wrapper for Flowchart JS library that makes it easy to draw a vector based flowchart diagram using SVG and Raphaël.js.

[You can see examples of it in this link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/jQuery-Plugin-To-Generate-SVG-Based-Flowchart-Diagram.html)